# change an image once after a number of minutes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change id="ads1" - id="ads6" with a different image that I set in java after 1 minute without random. but this code can run only id="ads1".

```js
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("ads1").src = "./assets/ads1.jpg";
      document.getElementById("ads2").src = "./assets/ads2.jpg";
      document.getElementById("ads3").src = "./assets/ads3.jpg";
      document.getElementById("ads4").src = "./assets/ads4.jpg";
      document.getElementById("ads5").src = "./assets/ads5.jpg";
      document.getElementById("ads6").src = "./assets/ads6.jpg";
      console.log("The image changed after 1 minute (60000 ms)");
  }, 60000);
}
```

```html
            <div>
<img id="ads1" src="./assets/image.jpg" alt="">
<img id="ads2" src="./assets/image.jpg" alt="">
<img id="ads3" src="./assets/image.jpg" alt="">
<img id="ads4" src="./assets/image.jpg" alt="">
<img id="ads5" src="./assets/image.jpg" alt="">
<img id="ads6" src="./assets/image.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
```

Comment: That's weird im trying to reproduce 6 image, but the "code snippet tool" only shows me the last 2 images. I recommend to check every single get element by id to avoid "undefined" case at runtime

Comment: The code seems all right, maybe add some query parameters to the image resource to make sure that the browser does not serve the cached image. For eg. `document.getElementById("ads1").src = "./assets/ads1.jpg?q=" + Date.now();`

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: @BasilBourque - I think OP is saving images, ads(*).jpg using Java, I could be wrong though!